# Ajax call returns 403 or 400 when POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Ajax script that returns successfully when passing no data values, but due to the constraint of another process, I believe the values we're passing is the culprit behind receiving a 400 error.

The AJAX call is as follows

```js
  type:"POST",
  url:"ajax/dashboards/totalexpend.php",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data:{site:(jmsite),date:(jmdate),dir:(jmdir)}, 
  success:function(data)
```

jmsite example

```
[Site].[OwnerDivSite].[Site].[883]
```

jmdate example

```
[YearMonth].[Month].[2017]&[1]
```

jmdir

```
[Direction].[Dir].[O]
```

The request is as follows according to Chrome

```
site=%22%5BSite%5D.%5BOwnerDivSite%5D.%5BSite%5D.%5B883%5D%22&date=%22%5BYearMonth%5D.%5BMonth%5D.%5B2017%5D%26%5B1%5D%22&dir=%22%5BDirection%5D.%5BDir%5D.%5BO%5D%22
```

I have tried using JSON.stringify on all values, as well as encodeURIComponent but neither have had any affect. I'm afraid it has to do with passing the brackets. I also tried setting the ajax call to traditional with no luck.

Thanks for the help!

EDITED

```
                var test_site = "'[Site].[OwnerDivSite].[Site].[883]'";
                var test_date = "'[YearMonth].[Month].[2017]&[1]'";
                var test_dir = "'[Direction].[Dir].&[O]'";

                var request = {site:test_site,date:test_date,dir:test_dir};

                var form_data = new FormData();

                for(var key in request) {

                    form_data.append(key, request[key]);
                }

                console.log(form_data);



                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"ajax/dashboards/totalexpend.php",
                        data: form_data,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        //data: JSON.stringify({site:msite,date:mdate,dir:mdir}), 
                        //contentType: "application/json",
                        //dataType: "json",
```

EDIT 2

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var test_site = "[Site].[OwnerDivSite].[Site].[883]";
var test_date = "[YearMonth].[Month].[2017]&[1]";
var test_dir = "[Direction].[Dir].&[O]";


var site = $.param( { sites: test_site }, true);
var dates = $.param( { dates: test_date }, true);
var dirs = $.param( { dirs: test_dir }, true);


new_data = { test_site,test_date,test_dir};

new_data = JSON.stringify(new_data);


    $.ajax
    ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax/dashboards/totalexpend.php",
        data: (new_data), 
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {               

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Well you are not sending up JSON.... `data: JSON.stringify({site:(jmsite),date:(jmdate),dir:(jmdir)}),`

Comment: @epascarello removing the datatype as json causes a 403 forbidden. I have tried using JSON.stringify on each value and that nets same result.

Comment: Did you try what I posted? stringify the whole thing, not each part.

Comment: @epascarello Ah, didn't realize to do the whole thing which makes perfect sense. I get a 403 when using that though. This is the request `{"site":"['[Site].[OwnerDivSite].[Site].[883]']","date":"['[YearMonth].[Month].[2017]&[1]']","dir":"['[Direction].[Dir].&[O]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[I]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[T]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[N]']"}`

Comment: @epascarello suggestion is is correct when posting with ajax to a endpoint accepting JSON, so what do you want to post exactly?

Comment: Is your endpoint public? if not in case of missing credentials/token returns 401 or 400?

Comment: @SilentTremor Yes, I am able to access it directly without providing any parameters.

Comment: Do you have a fiddler or postman working example?

Comment: What does the endpoint look like?

Comment: {"site":"['[Site].[OwnerDivSite].[Site].[883]']","date":"['[‌​YearMonth].[Month].[‌​2017]&[1]']","dir":"‌​['[Direction].[Dir].‌​&[O]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[I]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[T]', '[Direction].[Dir].&[N]']"} is a valid JSON and correct sent as @epascarello suggested, the problem is in a different place

Comment: @SilentTremor thanks for confirming that as correct.. working on Fiddler now.

Comment: the JSON is valid, but whether it matches what your endpoint is expecting is another matter. We don't have any details of that, though.

Comment: @ADyson it's not even reaching the endpoint. I can change the endpoint to a blank page and still same error.

Comment: are you using any kind of PHP framework which handles the requests?

Comment: What do you mean a black page? Is your endpoint accepting "JSON (aplication/json)" or is accepting "form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) with files" or "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: @ADyson no PHP framework. Server is Ubuntu with Apache and PHP 7 fastcgi

Comment: @SilentTremor I'm not sure I understand your question.. the Ajax call can't hit the endpoint at all as its returning forbidden. I'm not sure it matters what is in that file at this point, no?

Comment: Indeed but what is your endpoint/url accepting as request header "Content-Type"?

Comment: @SilentTremor response head states `Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: I asked about the request but you answered my question

Comment: So fast forward save that thing you want to post the: var requ= {site:(jmsite),date:(jmdate),dir:(jmdir)};

Comment: Next: var form_data = new FormData();

for ( var key in requ) {
    form_data.append(key, requ[key]);
}

Comment: @SilentTremor  here is the request header https://pastebin.com/UGf4Jxkn

Comment: FInaly: $.ajax({
    url         : 'ajax/dashboards/totalexpend.php',
    data        : form_data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(data){
    // do stuff
});

Comment: @SilentTremor also getting a 403 forbidden lol. This is the way the request body looks like https://pastebin.com/RvrhR69p

Comment: @SilentTremor Edited OP with most recent code

Comment: a 403 in Apache could be as simple as permissions on the filesystem.

Comment: @ADyson Very true, however I can navigate directly to this file via the browser, from the same domain as the ajax call.

Comment: @SilentTremor if I go back to my original code and remove the brackets, periods and & symbol, it posts fine. So I suppose its really just a matter of escaping the brackets.

Comment: It posts fine with the & symbol as well as the periods. So it's just the brackets now.

Comment: Are you still sending it with a "application/json" content type or not? If the brackets are within a string, and the data is sent with a JSON content-type I can't see that it would matter?? Incidentally why is your data enclosed within both double and single quotes? Is the endpoint expecting those single quotes included in the strings?

Comment: @ADyson Yes I am back to declaring it as json.. and I agree with it being in the string, but it is the observed behavior. If I remove the brackets from within the strings it works fine. Yes the endpoint expects the string to be identical to the OP.

Comment: and when using the JSON content-type, you get a 400, or a 403? Have you set "processData" true or false? Have you got "traditional" true or false? What does the body of the request look like in your browser's network tab? Sorry to be pedantic, I do want to help but it's the little details that can swing these things.

Comment: @ADyson haha I understand, and I certainly appreciate the help. I get 403 with JSON type declared. I have tried with traditional and processdata to true and false and still nothing. I've updated the OP with a standalone piece of script.

Answer (score 1):

One of those frustrating moments...

We had Mod_Security enabled on the Apache Server and it was hitting 2 rules, Repeatative Non-Word Chars and SQL Injection. We increased the 4 character repetitive rule, and removed [ and ] from the SQL Injection ruling.

If this does not solve your problem, please refer to the answers in the OP from
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898495/silenttremor and 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson

Rule to learn here, check Apache and PHP logs.

Comment: It happens, as all of us end up in this spot when we can't see the forest for the trees, glad you find the source of your problems.

Comment: glad you fixed it! I have to admit it wouldn't have occurred to me.